# Alamofire header throwing error: Cannot convert value of type to expected type

Tags: http-headers, swift2, alamofire

I am trying to make a POST request with Alamofire (header token authentication) but I am being thrown an error

> Cannot convert value of type '[String:String]' to expected argument type '[String:String]'

[image: Token header error]

How can I fix it?

This is my code:

```
func validationSuccessful() {

    let Auth_header = [ "Authorization" : Data.sharedInstance.token ]

    Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request(.POST, Data.weeklyEndpoint, headers: Auth_header, parameters: ["username": Data.sharedInstance.userName!, "password": Data.sharedInstance.passWord!]).responseJSON {
        response in

        if let result = response.result.value
        {
            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.result)

        }
        else
        {
            print("JSON data is nil.")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Data.sharedInstance.token is an optional... To fix this you can write

```
let Auth_header = [ "Authorization" : Data.sharedInstance.token ?? "" ]
```

But you should check if your token is nil first. For example:

```
guard let token = Data.sharedInstance.token else { print("Empty token"); return }
let Auth_header = [ "Authorization" : token ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some code look like this 
  AF.request(URL_THEARTER,method: .get, parameters:nil , encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: HTTPHeaders.init(BEARER_HEADER)).responseJSON { (reponse) in

Comment: There is something missing in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I also have same issue after struggle of four hours get rid off. Below link helps me to solve my problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50149146/7417935

Actually I printed response it clearly saying

> the app transport security policy requires secure connections.

As mentioned in above link we have to add the entry

> Add App Transport Security Settings as dictionary

and then add a child of Transport Security

> Allow Arbitrary Loads, as Boolean and set to true/YES.