# Error when grabbing data from API using Alamofire

Tags: swift, api, alamofire

Anyone know what to do with this error when trying to access an API from the internet using Alamofire. The strange thing is I have used the same function for other API's and they seem to work perfectly fine but not this.

The API is:

> http://minecraftpocket-servers.com/api/?object=servers&element=voters&key=833gowl7nz7jyqaqx96dagqzamn431yr9h&month=current&format=json&limit=10

Here is the error:

> Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could
>   not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the
>   use of a secure connection."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000004496c0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://minecraftpocket-servers.com/api/?object=servers&element=voters&key=833gowl7nz7jyqaqx96dagqzamn431yr9h&month=current&format=json&limit=10,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://minecraftpocket-servers.com/api/?object=servers&element=voters&key=833gowl7nz7jyqaqx96dagqzamn431yr9h&month=current&format=json&limit=10,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection.})

Here is the function I am trying to call.

```
func getAPIData(url: String) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {

                    let dataJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                    self.updateLabels(json: dataJSON)
                    print("Success!")

                } else {
                    print("Error: Could not get data.")
                    print("Error: ", response.error)
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you are not using a secure site(https), but a http.

Add this in your **info.plist**

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>example.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says, the app transport security policy requires secure connections.

You can enable arbitrary loads in your plist

Add the entry `Add App Transport Security Settings` as dictionary and add an Bool entry `Allow Arbitrary Loads`, set to true.

However I recommend using SSL if you have control over the server side. Using HTTPS will not trigger this error.